# Entity not managed exception while calling refresh() from spring scheduler

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I have created a scheduler class. From that class, I am invoking a service method, which is not a single transaction. The transaction is managed at the repository layer. 
The code will look like this,

```
public void doAction(int id){
  User user = repository.getUser(id);//transaction 1
   repository.updateStatus(user);// transaction 2
   repository.refresh():// call entityManager.refresh() internally
}
```

After getting User entity from repository, I am updating the status. Then user entity will be refreshed by calling entityManager.refresh(). 
But while calling refresh (), it is throwing an exception : InvalidArgumentException: Entity not managed.
Three calls are three different transactions.

But I am trying to call this method (doAction) from the Spring Controller, it is working fine. But calling from scheduler class is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these calls are made within their own transactions you need to call:

```
entityManager.merge(user);
```

before you call the `refresh(user)`. This entity needs to be in a managed state of the persistence context before you perform that operation. And when the previous transaction ends, it is in a detached state.

Comment: How it is working when invoking the same method from the Controller class?

Comment: Maybe the Controller starts a transaction and everything inside just propagates it and runs within it